# The number of transpositions in Symmetric group is $n(n-1)/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

How could I prove it?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
I found this in a book, can I take it as a proof? :
''Given the permutation ( 1 , 2) in Sn, what elements commute with it ?
Certainly any permutation leaving both I and 2 fixed does. There are
(n - 2) ! such. Also ( 1 , 2) commutes with itself. This way we get 2 (n - 2) !
elements in the group generated by ( 1 , 2) and the (n 2) ! permutations
leaving l and 2 fixed. Are there others? There are n(n - l ) /2 transpositions
and these are precisely all the conjugates of ( 1 , 2). Thus the conjugate
class of ( 1 , 2) has in it n(n - l ) /2 elements. If the order of the
normalizer of ( 1 , 2) is r, then, by our counting principle, n(n-1)/2''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply chose the two symbols to be used in the transposition, this is ${n\choose 2} = {n(n-1)\over 2}$.

Comment: Simple and easy, thank you.